# What is the difference between Selenium Grid and pytest-xdist plugin?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, selenium-grid, pytest-xdist

I'm new to parallel testing and I was wondering what the difference is between them.

Apparently, pytest-xdist does not need Selenium Grid to run. It can be used with Selenium alone.

Does anybody have any clue or resource where I can learn the difference?

Thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is useful for anybody I will write down what I learnt:

**pytest-xdist**: It is used for running parallel tests in the browsers that are installed in the local machine where tests will be run. This means that each test has a browser configured (e.g.: Firefox, Chrome) such as:

`driver = webdriver.Firefox()`

or

`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

And so each test will run with the driver that was specified in the code. Obviously, the local machine needs the browser drivers to be available in any *PATH* location, so that tests can be run with them.

**Selenium Grid**: It allows the execution of tests in different browsers, browser versions and operating systems configurations.

**Selenium Grid** combined with **pytest-xdist** allows the execution of parallel tests in different *browser-OS* environments (configured with capabilities, I think).

An execution command example would be:

`pytest -n5 -v -s -m "test or ready" --capability browserName firefox`

**-n5**: (pytest parameter) means that 5 instances of the browser will be launched simultaneously.

**test or ready**: these are the markers that can be combined to execute tests that have these markers.

**browserName firefox**: It is a capability that indicates that tests must be run in the specified browser, in this case, Firefox. Some possible values are: `chrome, firefox, internet explorer, safari`.

Some other capabilities are:

**version**: The browser version to use.

**platform**: The platform in which the browser will be executed. Some possible values are: `WINDOWS, XP, VISTA, MAC, LINUX, UNIX, ANDROID`.

To set up the Selenium Grid environment go along the following steps:

1. Download *selenium-server-standalone-[version].jar* from
   https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/.
2. Initiate the **HUB**:
   `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-[version].jar -role hub`
3. Initiate as many **NODES** as you want with:
   `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-[version].jar -role node -hub http://[URL_HUB]/wd/hub`
4. Configure a `RemoteDriver` in the tests, for example: `driver = webdriver.Remote( desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME, command_executor = 'http://[URL_HUB]:4444/wd/hub')`

I still need to learn how to pass the **capabilities args** as parameters for the `RemoteDriver`. In `conftest.py`file I can get the capabilities as a list with `config.getoption('--capability'))`. I still need to figure out how to pass the capabilities I want to the `setUp` method of all my tests.

If someone knows, I will really appreciate a hint on this.

I hope this helps someone who is as lost as I was at the beginning :)

Comment: Can we run multiple safari instances on one machine using selenium grid, please let me know if you have any details or steps for the same. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry @Rohit, I don't have further guides for this. I think that what you need is the pytest parameter -n. As far as I remember, it instantiates N workers to run in parallel on the same machine. I hope this answers your question. Regards!